# Basin of attraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, basins-of-attraction

Let $$g(x)=\frac{2}{5}x^3-\frac{7}{5}x$$. The fixed points are 0 and $$\sqrt6$$. There is a period-2 orbit of 1 and -1. The critical points are $$\sqrt\frac{7}{6}$$

a. calculate the Schwarzian derivative

$$sg(x)=\frac{-144x^2-84}{(6x^2-7)^2}$$<0 for all x

b.The point$$x0=\sqrt{7/6}$$ belongs to the basin of attraction of which orbit? What about $$-\sqrt{7/6}$$?

I have no idea what to do for part b...

Comment: How do you define the basin of attraction?

Comment: Just do it! That is, iterate $g$ starting at $x_0=\sqrt{7/6}$ a few times.  You should see a pattern emerge within 10 steps.